# How can I change the Visual Studio work environment from Web mode back to Visual C++ mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mode

I selected web development as my primary development style the first time I booted Visual Studio 2010 and now I would like to change it to Visual C++. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some poking around, the option to do this is:

```
"Tools" -> "Import and Export Settings" -> "Reset all settings"
```

Seems like a weird place for it

Comment: Does not apply to VS 2013.

Answer (score -1):

or you can just go to:

**Tools/Options/Environment/Start-up**

then choose from *At start-up box* >> 
**show new project dialog box**

so you can save time of switching between work environments!